# How to change/set Windows Time Zone in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm still new to perl and want to write a perl script/function that can set the timezone on a windows machine (locally) to a different time zone. For example if it's really Americas/Los_Angeles, I want to set it to something new like Americas/New_York or some other country's time zone. What's the best way to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about opening the Control Panel and doing it yourself? What are you using this for anyway...?

Answer (score 1):

`$ENV{TZ} = 'America/New_York';`

Be sure to follow [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753346/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-for-perls-localtime) - and advice about POSIX::tzset in particular - if you intend to use `localtime` in your script as well.