# When does a Perl script need to call `tzset` before calling `localtime`?

Tags: c, perl, timezone, posix, localtime

I recently learned [how to change the timezone returned by `localtime` in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753346/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-for-perls-localtime/753416#753416).

```
use POSIX qw(tzset);
print localtime . "\n";
$ENV{TZ} = 'America/Los_Angeles';
print localtime . "\n";
tzset;
print localtime . "\n";
```

Outputs

```
Wed Apr 15 15:58:10 2009
Wed Apr 15 15:58:10 2009
Wed Apr 15 12:58:10 2009
```

Notice how the hour only changes after calling `tzset`.

```
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

However, on my systems I'm getting,

```
Fri Jul 8 19:00:51 2016
Fri Jul 8 16:00:51 2016
Fri Jul 8 16:00:51 2016
```

Notice how on my system, the hour changes *without* calling `tzset`. This holds true on recent versions of Perl in Ubuntu and Illumos, as well as Perl `v5.8.8` on Solaris 10.

So if all my tests indicate that `tzset` has no effect, why / what other systems require `tzset` to be called explicitly? Do I still need to call `tzset` to remain compatible with certain environments, or is it now a thing of the past?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Time-and-Date  tl;dr - The system's notion of time of day and calendar date is controlled in widely different ways. Don't assume the timezone is stored in $ENV{TZ} , and even if it is, don't assume that you can control the timezone through that variable.

Comment: I would like something specific. My testing indicates it is safe not to call `tzset`. Since the software here is only intended for specific platforms, I do not want to tell our team to do extra work that is not needed. So, in what conditions do we need `tzset`?

Comment: An answer was posted and deleted, but links to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html, which says *"Local timezone information is used as though localtime() calls tzset()."*, so it sounds like `localtime` should call `tzset` automatically if the system is POSIX-compliant??? Is that the defining factor - whether the OS is POSIX-compliant?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: Starting with [Perl v5.8.9](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/cc93400aa5a8d556c56c28a8de644bd178d050d4/pod/perl589delta.pod#___top) (released in 2011) calling `tzset` when changing `$ENV{TZ}` isn't needed anymore.

---

Perl's `localtime` calls [`localtime_r(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) [internally](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/3f6b66c14467c0f8c7459e32c576618155ca89f3/pp_sys.c#L4744), which isn't required to  call `tzset(3)`. The [Linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html) advises:

> According to POSIX.1-2004, localtime() is required to behave as though
>   tzset(3) was called, while localtime_r() does not have this
>   requirement. For portable code tzset(3) should be called before
>   localtime_r().

In older non-multithreaded Perls, or if `localtime_r(3)` wasn't available during build, `localtime(3)` is used instead. In that case, a call to `tzset` would have been unnecessary, [per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html):

> Local timezone information is used as though localtime() calls tzset()

although there seem to have been times where [glibc didn't adhere to that](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=154):

> As for any code which doesn't call tzset all the time: **this definitly
>   won't change**.  It's far too expensive.  And for what?  The 0.000001%
>   of the people who take the laptops on a world tour and expect, e.g.,
>   syslog messages with dates according to the native timezone.  This is
>   not justification enough.  Just restart your machine.

This **did** change though and glibc now does act as if  `tztime(3)` was called, but only for non-reentrant `localtime` which might not be what your Perl was compiled to use.

There have been two Perl bug reports regarding this: [#26136](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=26136) and [#41591](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=41591).

As a fix, Perl now [decides at configuration time](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/7e69463d5ba4e34c2ea10a5c117a1777435209ec/Porting/Glossary#L1521) whether an implicit `tzset(3)` needs to be done, which makes specifying it in user code superfluous.